# How to find the sign of $\cos{2x}$ if $\tan{x}=2$?

Tags: trigonometry

Yeah, it looks really easy, but I got stuck with defining whether it's positive or negative. Its absolute value is $\frac 35$. But help me with finding the sign, please.

I know from trig identities that $\tan{x} = \frac {\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} = 2$. Therefore, $\sin{x} = 2\cos{x}$ and so $-3\sin{x}^2 = 4(\cos{x}^2 - \sin{x}) = 4\cos{2x}$. Now I am stuck. I know that $\sin{x}^2$ has a magnitude of $\frac {4}{5}$ by trial and error involving $\sin{x}^2 + \cos{x}^2 = 1$ but I don’t know how I would use that to find $\cos{2x}$.

Comment: How do you get the value $3/5$?

Comment: $$\cos(2\arctan(x))=\color{blue}{\cos^2(\arctan(x))}-\color{orange}{\sin^2(\arctan(x))}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(\arctan(x))}-\color{orange}{\frac{\tan^2(\arctan(x))}{1+\tan^2(\arctan(x))}}}=\frac{1}{1 + x^2}- \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=\cos(2x)$ and $g(x)=\tan(x)$ are periodic of period $\pi$. So we can assume that $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Since $1<\tan(x)$, we have that $x\in\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Therefore, $2x\in \left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$, so $\cos(2x)<0$.

---

Alternatively, since it seems from your post that you want to compute the value of  $\cos(2x)$, not only its sign, you can use that

$$\cos(2x) = \frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)} = \frac{1-4}{1+4} = -\frac{3}{5}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Remember that $\cos(2x) = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$ and $\tan x = 2$ implies $\sin x = 2\cos x$. Can you substitute one into the other and use the fact that $\cos^2 x > 0$?